# Google App Engine: Storing images in database (Python)

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, gql

I'm creating an ecommerce platform on Google App Engine using Python. For that, I need to store the details of the products I will be offering in a separate entity, which will also include an image of every individual product. Now, how do I store images in the datastore? Also, more importantly, how do I extract images from the database and display it for the user on my application?

EDIT:

After uploading my image into an 'Images' entity, I was trying to display it. Here's the code for the same:

main.py

```
class FileUpload(Handler):
    def post(self):
        file_upload = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
        file_name = file_upload.filename
        image = Images(id=file_name, file_name=file_name, blob=file_upload.file.read())
        image.put()

        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(image.file_name)[0]
        self.response.write(image.blob)
        self.final()

    def final(self):
        images = db.GqlQuery("Select * FROM Images WHERE file_name = 'CN.jpg'")
        self.render("template.html", images = images)

class Blob(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("blob.html")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/signup', Register),
                                ('/login', Login),
                                ('/logout', Logout),
                                ('/mp', MP),
                                (r'/file_upload', FileUpload),
                                ('/blob', Blob)], debug=True)
```

template.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    {%
        for image in images
    %}
    <div>{{image.blob}}</div>
    {%endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

blob.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div><input type="file" name="file"/></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, in template.html, I was expecting the image I was trying to extract to be displayed. However, I get the following error:

```
<div>{{image.blob}}</div>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Take a look at the blobstore.  Also see the images documentation.  There's probably something there that will be helpful:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic example of uploading an image, saving it in the datastore and serving the image.

fileupload.py:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import mimetypes


class Images(ndb.Model):
    file_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    blob = ndb.BlobProperty()


class FileUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        file_upload = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
        file_name = file_upload.filename
        image = Images(id=file_name, file_name=file_name, blob=file_upload.file.read())
        image.put()

        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(image.file_name)[0]
        self.response.write(image.blob)


class ImgServe(webapp2.Requesthandler):

    def get(self, resource):

        image = ndb.Key('Images', resource).get()
        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(image.file_name)[0]
        self.response.write(image.blob)
```

Here is the static form to post the image:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div><input type="file" name="file"/></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Routing the form post:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/file_upload', handler='fileupload.FileUpload')
```

Routing for the image server: `<img alt="test" src="/img_serve/test.png" />`

```
webapp2.Route(r'/img_serve/<resource:(.*)>', handler='fileupload.ImgServe'))
```

Comment: I have edited my original post. Couldn't display the image that was stored in the 'Images' entity in the datastore.

Comment: You cannot shown an image this way. You have to use an HTML <img> tag, which links to a handler (ImgServe) and shows the image like I showed in my example. Example: <img  alt="test" src="/img_serve/test.png" />

Comment: +1 for working and complete code. Maybe state that the key should be sent as `<img alt="test" src="/img_serve/{{ image.key.urlsafe() }}" />` and fetched in the handler by `image = ndb.Key(urlsafe=resource).get()`

Comment: By the way. There is a better way to serve images. If you save the images in the blobstore or cloudstorage (GCS), you can use a serving url. If you requst the image (GET the serving url) Google will serve the image. More info here: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcstest-python

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google High Performance Image Serving. You have to store or upload your images to the blobstore or Google Cloud Storage and create a serving_url.

The benefits:

- high performance
- Google will serve the images. You do not need a handler;
- cheap
- dynamic resizing and cropping.

More: Serving a blob in : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/
get_serving_url : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions

Comment: Can't I add images from my local machine into the datastore?

Comment: Yes you can. You can put the images in a blob property, but the size of the images is limited by the entity size. If you put the images in the datastore, you have to serve the images yourself.

Comment: See the example below.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, which you can decide between based upon the size of image and the workflow.

1. If the images are fixed and are only changed by the development team, you could include them as static files.
2. You can use [the blobstore api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) to enable uploading and viewing of images.
3. You can use [Google Cloud Storage libraries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) for uploading/viewing too.  I get the impression that Google is moving toward this rather than the blobstore.

Comment: Can't I add images from my local machine into the datastore?